# C++ function will not return

Tags: c++, class, function, return

I have a function that I am calling that runs all the way up to where it should return but doesn't return. If I cout something for debugging at the very end of the function, it gets displayed but the function does not return.

fetchData is the function I am referring to. It gets called by outputFile. cout displays "done here" but not "data fetched"

I know this code is messy but can anyone help me figure this out?

Thanks

```
  //Given an inode return all data of i_block data
  char* fetchData(iNode tempInode){
   char* data;
   data = new char[tempInode.i_size];
   this->currentInodeSize = tempInode.i_size;

   //Loop through blocks to retrieve data
   vector<unsigned int> i_blocks;
   i_blocks.reserve(tempInode.i_blocks);

   this->currentDataPosition = 0;
   cout << "currentDataPosition set to 0" << std::endl;
   cout << "i_blocks:" << tempInode.i_blocks << std::endl;
   int i = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    if(tempInode.i_block[i] == 0)
     break;
    i_blocks.push_back(tempInode.i_block[i]);
   }

   appendIndirectData(tempInode.i_block[12], &i_blocks);
   appendDoubleIndirectData(tempInode.i_block[13], &i_blocks);
   appendTripleIndirectData(tempInode.i_block[14], &i_blocks);

   //Loop through all the block addresses to get the actual data
   for(i=0; i < i_blocks.size(); i++){
    appendData(i_blocks[i], data);
   }
   cout << "done here" << std::endl;

   return data;
  }




  void appendData(int block, char* data){
   char* tempBuffer;
   tempBuffer = new char[this->blockSize];

   ifstream file (this->filename, std::ios::binary);
   int entryLocation = block*this->blockSize;
   file.seekg (entryLocation, ios::beg);
   file.read(tempBuffer, this->blockSize);

   //Append this block to data
   for(int i=0; i < this->blockSize; i++){
    data[this->currentDataPosition] = tempBuffer[i];
    this->currentDataPosition++;
   }
   data[this->currentDataPosition] = '\0';
  }

  void outputFile(iNode file, string filename){
   char* data;
   cout << "File Transfer Started" << std::endl;
   data = this->fetchData(file);
   cout << "data fetched" << std::endl;

   char *outputFile = (char*)filename.c_str();
   ofstream myfile;
   myfile.open (outputFile,ios::out|ios::binary);
   int i = 0;
   for(i=0; i < file.i_size; i++){
    myfile << data[i];
   }
   myfile.close();
   cout << "File Transfer Completed" << std::endl;
   return;
  }
```

Comment: What you're doing is something called "`printf` debugging," and it's generally not recommended. You're going to need to use an actual debugger.

Also, please indent more than one space per tab level. This is just impossible to read...

Comment: @rlbond almost all the debugging I do is "printf debugging" - there is absolutely nothing wrong with the practice.

Comment: Printf debugging works great for figuring out general areas of failure, but for the details, debuggers help more.

Comment: 2st: sometimes it's much easier to use printf's.

Comment: @peachy For the details, I tend to rely on thinking.

Comment: @Neil: You're correct; I suppose I was too harsh. What I really meant was more along the lines of "I don't recommend it as your only method of debugging."

Comment: There are three ways to debug: with a debugger, printf debugging, and psychic debugging.  The last one often trumps the others, although it is completely unreliable.

Comment: Technically this is not 'printf' debugging but 'cout' debugging. Isn't there a difference between the way that these two output mechanisms work in respect of buffering? Could this explain why "data fetched" is not being displayed? (i.e. could it have been executed but not yet flushed to stdio?) In any case, I'd suggest attaching to the running process with the debugger for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either there's some other line of code in your program that prints "done here", or you're corrupting the stack and affected the return address.  But I don't see any buffers on the stack that you could overrun.

Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Ok, I am using Visual C++ 2008 Express and haven't actually used the debugger before now. I set a breakpoint at cout << "done here" and noticed that the value shown for currentDataPosition is in red. I imagine this means something is wrong there?

Comment: When you run the debugger and reach the breakpoint, do you see any errors? If you step through and hit the return, where does execution go?

Comment: Ok at the breakpoint of the return statement I got this error:
First-chance exception at 0x77004230 in ext2Interface.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

Comment: Does anyone know how I go about fixing this First-chance exception?

Comment: I was overflowing the data array in the appendData function.

Comment: @Mike: red means the value has changed.

Answer (score 2):

Set breakpoints, step through in a debugger, and see where the actual execution starts to differ from what you think should happen.

From a quick look at your code, you should get the second message, but going through in a debugger and seeing what really happens will help more than any theoretical musings on what could be going wrong. It also looks like you'll  be leaking memory everywhere, I don't see any `delete`s to go with your `new`s.

Answer (score 1):

If appendData() keeps appending to i_blocks then the data structure keeps growing and so does i_blocks.size(). This will never exit !!!

```
   //Loop through all the block addresses to get the actual data
   for(i=0; i < i_blocks.size(); i++){
    appendData(i_blocks[i], data);
   }
```

Comment: But the OP says that "done here" is displayed, which means that part finishes.

Comment: Except Mike said that the "done here" line is displayed, and that printf comes after the call to appendData() and immediately before return.

Comment: That part does finish as the others have said. appendData isn't adding more values onto the array. It is setting the values that are already there.